# Unnecessary ROLLBACK's with BasicDataSource from commons-dbcp

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

If `BasicDataSource` from *Apache commons-dbcp* (version 1.4, as I'm limited to Java 1.6) is configured with `defaultAutoCommit=false`, then two extra `ROLLBACK`'s are executed, one when a database connection is taken from the pool, and another one when returning a connection to the pool.

The corresponding stack traces are (*Oracle Thin*'s `T4CConnection` example):

```
T4CConnection(PhysicalConnection).rollback() line: 1950 
PoolableConnection(DelegatingConnection).rollback() line: 368   
PoolableConnectionFactory.passivateObject(Object) line: 685 
BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(PoolableConnectionFactory) line: 1559 
BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory, KeyedObjectPoolFactory, AbandonedConfig) line: 1545  
BasicDataSource.createDataSource() line: 1388   
BasicDataSource.getConnection() line: 1044
```

and

```
T4CConnection(PhysicalConnection).rollback() line: 1950 
PoolableConnection(DelegatingConnection).rollback() line: 368   
PoolableConnectionFactory.passivateObject(Object) line: 685 
GenericObjectPool.addObjectToPool(Object, boolean) line: 1379   
GenericObjectPool.returnObject(Object) line: 1342   
PoolableConnection.close() line: 90 
PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close() line: 191
```

Thus, each successful database transaction is a sequence of:

1. `ROLLBACK`
2. do something with the database connection
3. `COMMIT`
4. `ROLLBACK`

(instead of a single `COMMIT`), while each failed one is a sequence of

1. `ROLLBACK`
2. do something with the database connection
3. `ROLLBACK`
4. `ROLLBACK`

(instead of a single `ROLLBACK`).

This behaviour applies an additional pressure to the redo and undo subsystems (particularly, in *Oracle* case, but the problem holds for any database accessed via *commons-dbcp*, e. g.: I observed the same issue with *MySQL*).

How can I get rid of these extra `ROLLBACK`'s while still having my data source configured with `defaultAutoCommit=false` (i. e. without the need to manually call `setAutoCommit(false)` for each connection taken from the data source)?

Alternatively, how can I mitigate the issue from *Oracle* side (i. e. without changing my code or replacing libraries)?